# Move sprite diagonally

Tags: xna, logic, sprite, draw

I hope you can help me.

I'm moving my sprite according to mouse position when user clicks with the right button like this:

```
protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    int nextX = SpritePosition.X;
    int nextY = SpritePosition.Y;
    int SpriteWidth = 135;
    int SpriteHeight = 135;
    int Speed = 3;

    MouseState ms = Mouse.GetState();
    if (ms.RightButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
    {
        if (ms.X > SpritePosition.X + SpriteWidth) //check to move right
        {
            nextX = SpritePosition.X + Speed;
        }
        else if (ms.X < SpritePosition.X) //check to move left
        {
            nextX = SpritePosition.X - Speed;
        }

        if (ms.Y > SpritePosition.Y + SpriteHeight) //Check to move bottom
        {
            nextY = SpritePosition.Y + Speed;
        }
        else if (ms.Y < SpritePosition.Y) //Check to move top
        {
            nextY = SpritePosition.Y - Speed;
        }

        //Change the Sprite position to be updated in the DRAW.
        SpritePosition = new Rectangle(nextX, nextY, graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width, graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height);
    }

    base.Update(gameTime);
}
```

It's working right now, but the way it's moving is like this:

Wrong moving https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jb5EL.png

The way i want it to move like:
Right moving https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHmzm.png

Guys, now i tried the following, from the answers below:

```
            Vector2 From = new Vector2(SpritePosition.X, SpritePosition.Y);
            Vector2 To = new Vector2(ms.X, ms.Y);
            From = Vector2.Subtract(From,To );
            Vector2 Direction = Vector2.Normalize(From);
            Direction = Direction * Speed;

            SpritePosition = new Vector2(Direction.X, Direction.Y);
```

My sprite isn't moving, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think my example is perhaps too much, it seems that you only forgot to calculate the sprite's size. So, if you click a location with the mouse you'd want it to be centered on that point. Then, X = MouseLocation.X - (SpriteWidth / 2), Y = MouseLocation.Y - (SpriteHeight / 2). With a closer look at your examples it seems that this is the problem.

Comment: Update your browser and you'll see my working example below your code, hopefully this works for you. However, I believe the comment above is also a possibility for a solution.

Comment: The problem is not that i want it to me in the middle, the problem is the way it's moving, it's not going straight diagonally, if the size of Y is less than X, the move goes first to Y while going to X but Y finishes first (it's lower than X) and then the sprite continues to go to X. I want it to go straight diagonally

Comment: Create a new XNA Game project and copy my example code below, the code is working and perhaps you can learn something from it what you did wrong. Whatever the problem is.

Comment: Remove the Program.cs file and just add a sprite that you want as the "Sprite" and rename it to dot, to try it.

Comment: Thanks mate, marked as answer and made I a comment there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made an example with my code below, here it is:

http://pastebin.com/ep659g76

I created a simple dot, 5x5 pixels that is the object on screen. 
You can change to whatever you like it to be.

This is a method I've used for a topdown shooter with a spriteanimation. I converted it from C++ to C#, but it should work the same. In my case, depending on how the sprite is located I had to add a rotation of +90 degrees to get the correct result, but hopefully you figure that out.

```
public static class Helper_Direction
{

    // Rotates one object to face another object (or position)
    public static double FaceObject(Vector2 position, Vector2 target)
    {
        return (Math.Atan2(position.Y - target.Y, position.X - target.X) * (180 / Math.PI));
    }

    // Creates a Vector2 to use when moving object from position to a target, with a given speed
    public static Vector2 MoveTowards(Vector2 position, Vector2 target, float speed)
    {
        double direction = (float)(Math.Atan2(target.Y - position.Y, target.X - position.X) * 180 / Math.PI);

        Vector2 move = new Vector2(0, 0);

        move.X = (float)Math.Cos(direction * Math.PI/180) * speed;
        move.Y = (float)Math.Sin(direction * Math.PI / 180) * speed;

        return move;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, if the player was at the center of the screen (or map) the enemies use this method to simply work towards that object and also to rotate their sprite so it looks as if they're walking towards you.

Comment: Mate this worked like a charm, but to tell you the truth, I didn't understand how that MoveTowards function work, I'm bad with Math :/

Comment: You can look it up, it calculates a trajectory. And if you later have a "Character sprite" that you want to rotate so that it points toward the point you're walking to, you can use "FaceObject" and as I stated earlier perhaps you need to create an offset, say if you're character is pointed upwards (in the Texture2D image) you might have to add Math.ToRadians(FaceObject(Position, Target)+90f) in your spriteBatch.Draw call.

Answer (score 2):

You have two positions, store both as a Vector2.

Subtract current location from target location to get the Vector between the two points.

Normalize that vector to get a direction vector.

Multiply the direction vector by your movement speed to move along the direction vector at the  desired speed.

Comment: Can you please provide me some code? i've just started working with XNA. How can I subtract 2 vectors and normalize?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.vector2(v=xnagamestudio.35).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to change position to:

```
nextY = SpritePosition.Y + SpriteHeight + Speed;
```

But this would cause for sprite to jump on start so I advise you to first calculate finish position and then move it to that position slowly.